# when install angular cli Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...gsJjnNLbV\nxrOnxOWiCk'

Tags: angular

```
C:\Users\AA>node --version
v12.17.0


C:\Users\AA>npm --version
6.14.4

npm, install -g @angular/CLI
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...gsJjnNLbV\nxrOnxOWiCk'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-07T05_09_58_878Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please add more content about your question. You have just added only the errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to cache may got corrupted.

Try below command on command prompt. Recommended project directory.

```sh
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Hi i tried the method。 but 
npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@schematics%2fupdate (over 30000ms)